# How to export a task list in sharepoint 2010 to another site

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, export, workflow

I'm migrating a sharepoint site from the root site collection to another site collection in the way that my old url is http://domain.com/sitename and the new site is in http://domain.com/sites/sitename. I'm using the Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb command line tools to execute this operation. The operation is successfully executed, all the library, lists, etc are exported just fine. Except the site's Tasks list. =( The old completed tasks are not important for me, but the newly assigned tasks are. So the way is to get all of them just as the original site. The list associated to the workflow that generetes the tasks is exported just fine also. But not the tasks. I appreciate your help. Hugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create Task list template and move this template to another site manually.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx#_Create_a_list

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to give you the worth feedback. It's just correct.